# How to add geojson point to openlayers 3/4 map and make it clickable to open popup with properties in it?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Using openlayers 3/4, I am having issues drawing a featurecollection containing only points. All I want to do is draw the point on the map, and make it so when you click on it, a popup shows and it displays the one properties it has.

The error I am getting is:
core.js:1448 ERROR TypeError: a.Yf is not a function
    at ol.js:152

My code is:

```
let points = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            'text':'World',
            'id': 'Point 1'
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [somecoords]
        }
    }]
};

var thepoint = new ol.source.Vector({
    title: 'Hello Point',
    features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(points)
  });

  map.addLayer(thepoint);
```

What is the issue? How can I accomplish this? The error is not clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your post doesn't contain enough information about your coords.  A jsfiddle example showing the problem makes these things much easier to solve.

I suggest following this geoJSON example:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson.html

Pay close attention to map projection, if your geoJSON is correct and you see no points on the map, your projection is most likely wrong for the coordinates used:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html#how-do-i-change-the-projection-of-my-map-

On Selection, see this doc:

Selection example here https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-features.html